# Access a variable from outside of the script with jQuery on an Image Map

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm currently trying to get my head around arrays and how to utilise them with jQuery.

I have an image map, and I want to create several arrays to input the data into the image map HTML with jQuery.

Here's what I've attempted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var type = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.fancybox({
        'title': title,
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'href' : url,
        'type' : type,
          closeBtn    : true,
    maxWidth  : 467,
    maxHeight  : 609,
    fitToView  : false,
    padding   : '5',
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect  : 'none'
    });
  $('.fancybox').attr('title', altTitle);
});

  var slideTitles = [   "Title 0",
                        "Title 1",
                        "Title 2"
                     ]; 

  var altTitle =  [    "This is ALT tag 0",
                       "This is ALT tag 1",
                       "This is ALT tag 2"
                     ]; 
});
```

Where I'm struggling is how to access the arrays outside of the script in the HTML (the Google Analytics event tracking especially)...

The HTML:

```
<img src="test.jpg" width="800" height="480" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="59,132,227,367" href="test1.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', slideTitles, altTitle, 'testing action']);" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="304,108,483,382" href="test2.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', slideTitles, altTitle, 'testing action']);" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="514,46,747,441" href="test3.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', slideTitles, altTitle, 'testing action']);" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to make your variables global. Not that it's good design, I think the module pattern with public methods to access the arrays is cleaner.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      var type = $(this).attr('rel');
      $.fancybox({
          'title': title,
          'titlePosition': 'inside',
          'href' : url,
          'type' : type,
           closeBtn    : true,
           maxWidth  : 467,
           maxHeight  : 609,
           fitToView  : false,
           padding   : '5',
           openEffect  : 'none',
           closeEffect  : 'none'
      });
      $('.fancybox').attr('title', altTitle);
  });

  // Marking global variables with window.globalName is clearer
  // than just not using var
  window.slideTitles = ["Title 0","Title 1","Title 2"];     
  window.altTitle =  ["This is ALT tag 0", "This is ALT tag 1", "This is ALT tag 2"]; 
});

<img src="test.jpg" width="800" height="480" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="59,132,227,367" href="test1.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', window.slideTitles, window.altTitle, 'testing action']);" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="304,108,483,382" href="test2.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', window.slideTitles, window.altTitle, 'testing action']);" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="514,46,747,441" href="test3.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', window.slideTitles, window.altTitle, 'testing action']);" />
</map>
```

A better solution would be to add the handlers with jQuery instead of inline script in the HTML

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slideTitles = ["Title 0","Title 1","Title 2"];    
  var altTitle =  ["This is ALT tag 0", "This is ALT tag 1","This is ALT tag 2"];
  $('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      var type = $(this).attr('rel');
      $.fancybox({
          'title': title,
          'titlePosition': 'inside',
          'href' : url,
          'type' : type,
           closeBtn    : true,
           maxWidth  : 467,
           maxHeight  : 609,
           fitToView  : false,
           padding   : '5',
           openEffect  : 'none',
           closeEffect  : 'none'
      });
      $('.fancybox').attr('title', altTitle);

      // This reads the attribute "data-index" from the html
      // This requires that your HTML know about your JS array, which is tight coupling
      // Another approach would be to store the title and alt text in the HTML
      // and just retrieve them here. If you need them in more places, you're probably
      // better off using the array
      var index = $(this).data("index");
      // Do what you need here instead of with inline handlers
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', slideTitles[index], altTitle[index], 'testing action'])           
  });
});
```

**If this is the only place that needs the array, I would do the following**

```
<img src="test.jpg" width="800" height="480" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="59,132,227,367" href="test1.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" data-title="Title 1" data-alt="Alt 1"/>
  <area shape="rect" coords="304,108,483,382" href="test2.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" data-title="Title 2" data-alt="Alt 2"/>
  <area shape="rect" coords="514,46,747,441" href="test3.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe" data-title="Title 3" data-alt="Alt 2" />
</map>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this); // it's wasteful to keep calling $(this)
      $.fancybox({
          title: title,
          titlePosition: 'inside',
          href :  $this.attr('href'),
          type : type,
          closeBtn    : true,
          maxWidth  : 467,
          maxHeight  : 609,
          fitToView  : false,
          padding   : '5',
          openEffect  : 'none',
          closeEffect  : 'none'
      });
      $('.fancybox').attr('title', $this.data('alt'));
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', $this.data('title'), $this.data('alt'), 'testing action'])           
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for a quick reply. Please excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean by: 'A better solution would be to also add the are handlers with jQuery'. This is the kind of thing I want to learn how to do properly so I'll research it once I know what I'm looking for!

Comment: See my second example, feel free to ask further questions. Please excuse that unparsable sentence :)

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you. Now what I'm trying to figure out is how to assign the numbers to the image map href links, so that when the third one is clicked on, it knows to read the third array item... Fun! :)

Comment: Let me suggest something... give me a second

Comment: @JayDee There, added an example of how add an index to the html so you know which item from the array to retrieve, I would consider adding the data (title, alt) into the HTML since your HTML shouldn't have intimate knowledge of your JS (the map tag has to know the index of a JS array)